# SQL Server: how-to retrieve performance metrics programmatically; specifically logical reads

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

*Background:* I have a very complex stored procedure that dynamically creates SQL based on  ten parameters. On top of this, it uses some views, which are themselves quite complicated. As one can imagine, in some cases, the resulting SQL statement generates quite a few (as in trillions in the worst case) logical reads. I have several strategies that I'm working through.

*Test harness:* I've created a diagnostic stored procedure that runs the stored procedure with various parameters settings and stores the results out to a table. This records the output and parameter set used to generate it.

*What I'm missing:* I want to capture performance metrics programmatically. I don't want to have to run each test and then write them down. I have twenty some-odd parameter sets and growing. And I'm comparing different versions of the stored proc too.

*What I think I want:* 'Set statistics IO ON'  gives me what I'm looking for, but the information shows up in the 'messages' tab. **Is there a way to have this information returned so that my stored proc can put these values into my results table?**

This is a sample of the queries created to test my stored proc. This code sample is generated 60+ times (once per parameter set per test proc). This specific iteration tests the 'ORIGINAL' stored proc with parameter set number 11.

```
DECLARE @LSBA_table table (ViewStatementBalanceAllUid uniqueidentifier, AccountResponsiblePartyUid uniqueidentifier, FinancialCenterUid uniqueidentifier, FinancialCenterName varchar(255), Balance money, CycleTrigger BIT, LastStatementDate Date, AccountResponsiblePartyFullName varchar(255), LastName varchar(255), ExternalID varchar(25), PayerCreditBalance Money, StatementsByFinancialCenter bit, SendStatement bit);
INSERT INTO @LSBA_table EXEC LoadStatementBalanceAll_ORIGINAL  @nameRangeSearch = 'A-Bzzz',  @onDemand = 0, @daysBack=30, @financialCenterUid='7FAEF75C-914F-491F-8FE2-0A747FD84088;8709E580-13BC-4E4B-9325-D8F3AB1B2868', @minBalance=25.00
INSERT INTO CUS_LSBA_RESULTS (StoredProcName, ParameterId,ViewStatementBalanceAllUid,AccountResponsiblePartyUid,FinancialCenterUid,FinancialCenterName,Balance,CycleTrigger,LastStatementDate,AccountResponsiblePartyFullName,LastName,ExternalID,PayerCreditBalance,StatementsByFinancialCenter,SendStatement) (SELECT 'LoadStatementBalanceAll_ORIGINAL', 11, * FROM @LSBA_table)
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to redesign some stuff here. Dynamic sql can be an absolute nightmare to wrangle and it sounds like you are into the ugly side of dynamic sql. And what about those views? Do you have nested views (meaning views that call views)? Trillions of reads is a sign that something has gone very wrong unless you are dealing with several trillion rows.

Comment: For the question at hand I don't know of a way to return those values.

Comment: Also be ware of [some instances where it returns unreliable data](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/beware_statistics_io).

Comment: @SeanLange, agreed. It is a monumental pain in the @$$. I hate and despise dynamic SQL but I've been instructed to 'MAKE IT WORK'. There's some internal political-ness to it. :( But that just means I have what I have, and i'm going to do what I can with in the confines provided.

Comment: @scsimon, What do you mean? Is the returned data not to be trusted? Do you know under what circumstances this is the case? Is there way to know if the results *are valid* ?

Comment: @Displayname Aaron details it in [**that article I linked in my comment**](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/beware_statistics_io). Since you didn't post the query, it was just a FYSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to save the results automatically of

```
 set statistic IO on
```

There is no way to do this. But you can get all the results from creating a profiler trace which can save everything you want (every conceivable stats) from running different versions of the same query. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017